# SQLITE_ERROR - SQL error or missing database (near "RAISE": syntax error)

Tags: sqlite

I'm attempting to write the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SightingLocationError
  AFTER INSERT ON SIGHTINGS
  WHEN LOCATION NOT IN FEATURES
BEGIN
  RAISE(ABORT,
  'ERROR: Insert into SIGHTINGS table references location' + LOCATION + 'that is not found in the database.'
  );
END;
```

But it's throwing this error:

```
sql> CREATE TRIGGER SightingLocationError
  AFTER INSERT ON SIGHTINGS
  WHEN LOCATION NOT IN FEATURES
BEGIN
  RAISE(ABORT,
  'ERROR: Insert into SIGHTINGS table references location' + LOCATION + 'that is not found in the database.'
  );
END
[2017-12-02 13:25:12] [1] [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "RAISE": syntax error)
```

I've tried formatting the string different ways and changing the query up, but I keep getting the same error no matter what I try. Can anyone show me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You're trying to execute Oracle PL/SQL on sqlite.

Comment: What specifically is the issue or is written in Oracle PL/SQL? I was following the trigger tutorial located [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-trigger/), and that's how it's formatted on there.